# Why do we make objects of JFrame and other such Swing components while we import them?

Tags: swing, import, jpanel

```
package calculator;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class Calculator_Ui implements ActionListener {
  JFrame Jframe = new JFrame("MyCalculator");
  JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
  JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(1, 20);
}
```

Comment: You might want to read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), which enhances the probability for getting a useful answer _drastically_. You might find [ESR](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eric_S._Raymond)'s excellent essay [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) helpful, too.

Comment: Markus W Mahlberg, You may be a professor or P.h.d Scholar but I am learning this time, want some logical answer

Comment: And I want to have an island in the Carribean, filled with hot bikini models and a pipeline to my favorite brewery. It is not about what you want. It is about rules (one of them is [to play nice](http://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice) ). Please be advised that it is basic netiquette to follow them. One of them is that Stackoverflow is dedicated to "practical, detailed questions" (aka "_coding_ problems") and not for teaching basics, if you mind to read the [intro tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: Well, I think there is no any rule in Stackoverflow to ask only Coding questions. Many others in this site ask basic questions.if your level or status does not allow you to answer such questions then leave please... Don't waste your time

Comment: Right from the tour, for your highnesses' notice: "Ask about _specific_ programming problems, software algorithms, coding techniques and software development tools." Furthermore, you are required to show effort that you tried to find an answer to your question. And last but not least, your question seems to be pretty much [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and believe it or not, some people take the time to give back by cleaning up. And as a personal word: the very last person in the world I allow to shut me up is you.

Comment: *"..want some logical answer"*  It seems to me that the advice offered by @MarkusWMahlberg was aimed at getting you exactly that.  Don't shoot the messenger simply because you don't like the message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Importing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/usepkgs.html) just means you don't have to type fully qualified package name when using swing components in your code like:

```
javax.swing.JFrame Jframe = new javax.swing.JFrame("MyCalculator");
```

In this way, you could avoid import statements but increases effort to type.

While to use libraries, you would need to [instantiate](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html) the object by allocating space in heap for your object and that's what you are doing by statement:

```
JFrame Jframe = new JFrame("MyCalculator");
```